# What are characters called when they have three of the same radical used?

Tags: characters, etymology, traditional-characters, writing, radicals

I sometimes encounter characters like 鑫, which is made of three 金 radicals, or 龘, which is made of three 龍 radicals. What are they called and is there a reason for their existence? Ive tried looking online but havent found a good resource yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**maybe**, called “三疊字”, have a look of this page

[10個少見「三疊字」 你識唔識讀？](https://topick.hket.com/article/1188057/10%E5%80%8B%E5%B0%91%E8%A6%8B%E3%80%8C%E4%B8%89%E7%96%8A%E5%AD%97%E3%80%8D%20%E4%BD%A0%E8%AD%98%E5%94%94%E8%AD%98%E8%AE%80%EF%BC%9F)

[image]

btw, the wiki page:

[https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/三叠字](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E4%B8%89%E5%8F%A0%E5%AD%97)

have fun :)

edited.

i checked a book in literary chinese, it was called “**三字**”. a famous (imo, only) story: three literati composed verses using “三字”, while drinking alcohol

> 陳詢出為同知，同僚餞之。令各用**三字**分合，以韻相協，以成句終之。

> 陳循云：「轟字三個車，余斗字成斜。車、車、車，遠上寒山石徑斜。」

> 高轂云：「品字三個口，水酉字成酒。口、口、口，勸君更盡一杯酒。」

> 詢自云：「矗字三個直，黑出字成黜。直、直、直，焉往而不三黜。」

[簷曝雜記 volume 5, page 92](https://archive.org/details/02095976.cn/page/n92/mode/1up)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Looked up 曡字 in Pleco and it also seemed to highlight the same thing. Thanks! I think I'm going to use this piece of paper as an example one day haha

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand, great, you get what you want  now try to comprehend the provided story, quite interesting 